# get max of qint64 number and scalar?

Tags: c++

How can I get the max value of a  qint64 number and scalar?

The following does not work. I guess because std::max neither accepts not returns qint64.

```
qint64 fromTimeStamp = -1;
qint64 fromTimeStampNonNegative = std::max(fromTimeStamp, 0);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not that `qint64` is not know to `std::max`. It is simply a typedef for `long long`. The real reason this does not work is that you specify two different template types:

The (simplified) signature of std::max is

```
template <typename T>
T max(T a, T b);
```

If you call it with your arguments, you have 2 different types `T`. On the one hand, `qint64`, on the other hand `int` (determinted from the `0` literal). This does not work as the compiler requires the two arguments to be of the same type.

All you have to do is ensure they are or explicitly specify the template type. All of the following examples will do so and thus work:

- `std::max(fromTimeStamp, 0ll);`
- `std::max(fromTimeStamp, static_cast<qint64>(0));`
- `std::max<qint64>(fromTimeStamp, 0);`